# Can't find Aptana Studio file

Tags: software-installation, aptana-studio

I am new to Ubuntu.

When I tried to install Aptana Studio, everything works until the end when I try to unzip it. It says `no such file or directory`. If I search with `ls` then it returns the same result

[image]

Comment: why are you root and what "everything" do you mean when you say everything works and what "unzip" do you mean when you try to unzip it? What instructions are you following, what commands did you enter, what error messages did you receive when trying to complete the installation?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be in the `/root` directory and not in `/`. This is the home directory of root. You can easily confirm this by typing

```
pwd
```

(`pwd` = print working directory)
if you want to go to the root directory (meaning the root of the directory tree `/`), you need to type from where you are

```
cd ..
```

or

```
cd /
```

The software you are trying to install is most probably not installed in the home directory of root as this would be a rather impractical place (only root could run the program).

I would guess that it is installed in `/opt`